# Doit-on dire « Il abandonne ses cours à la mention « bien » ou « Il abandonne ses classes alors qu’il est à la mention « bien » »

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation

En parlant de cote universitaire.

Il abandonne ses classes à la mention « bien » ou  Il abandonne ses classes alors qu’il est à la mention « bien » ?

Il abandonne ses classes à la mention « bien ». Il abandonne ses classes alors qu’il est à la mention « bien ». Il est fou!

N’hésitez pas à me faire part d’autres tournures si vous jugez utiles d'autres façons d'exprimer ce fait!

Je cherche à mieux m’exprimer. Merci

Comment: Tu peux nous en dire plus sur la cote universitaire dont il est question, et qui abandonne quoi exactement, et pourquoi ?

Comment: Il s’agit d’un étudiant qui abandonne une classe. En ce qui concerne la cote, elle est une mesure de la compréhension d’un étudiant par rapport aux autres étudiants de la classe. A+ (4.3) - Mention Très Très bien. A (4.0) - Mention Très bien. B+ (3.6) Mention Bien. Etc.

Comment: En bref il s’agit d’un étudiant qui abandonne sa classe dès qu’il est certain qu’il ne pourra obtenir la mention « Très bien » en se basant sur ses résultats actuels.

Comment: et que signifie *abandonner sa classe* ? Que va faire cet étudiant après ?

Comment: Cela signifie que ledit étudiant ne se présentera plus en classe et se verra attribuer la mention « abandon » dans son relevé de notes.

Comment: Ok, je vois. Donc ce ne doit pas être en France car ici, la présence d'un étudiant n'est pas vérifiée ni obligatoire. Ce qui compte, c'est la présence et les résultats aux examens...

Comment: Pour être précis, la présence aux cours magistraux n'est pas obligatoire mais des absences répétées et non justifiées aux TD (travaux dirigés) peuvent être éliminatoires en France. J'ai vu que "cote universitaire" semblait un terme plus courant au Québec. Tu es Canadien ?

Comment: En effet, jilliagre. Je te remercie de m’avoir donner de ton temps.

Comment: « j'ai laissé tomber l'anglais », « j'ai lâché le cours de math » à la rigueur, mais c'est vrai que je n'ai jamais entendu dire « abandonner une classe » (cela évoque « abandonner une classe de CP dans la forêt »), ça doit être un jargon tout neuf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aucune des deux expressions n'est aisément compréhensible pour un Français de France.

Personne<sup>1</sup> ne dit ici *abandonner ses classes* dans le cas décrit. On pourrait le dire d'un enseignant qui laisse tomber ses élèves, pas l'inverse. Le seul cas où *ses classes* était utilisé avec ce sens, c'était du temps de la conscription obligatoire (service militaire) et dans se cas, [faire ses classes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_ses_classes) correspondait à la formation initiale. Abandonner ses classes correspondait donc alors à une désertion.

*À la mention bien* n'est pas très clair non plus car cela signifie qu'il a déjà obtenu cette mention, et qu'il n'a donc plus la possibilité d'abandonner.

Ce que j'écrirais pour décrire cette situation pourrait être, par exemple:

> Il abandonne son UE<sup>2</sup> de biologie cellulaire alors qu'il se dirigeait vers une mention bien.

> Il abandonne ses TD de droit civil et perd cette UE alors qu'il aurait pu avoir la mention bien.

> Il laisse laisse tomber le sanskrit alors qu'il était au niveau de la mention bien au contrôle continu.

<sup>1: L'expression semble présente au Québec, peut-être sous l'influence de l'anglais *to abandon his classes* ?</sup>

<sup>2: UE : Unité d'enseignement ou UCTS, correspond à une matière enseignée à l'université en France. Avant, on parlait d'UV (Unité de valeur).</sup>

Comment: "*Personne ne dit abandonner ses classes.*" Je ne suis pas sûre que vous ayez raison dans le contexte du français en général. Je suis d'accord qu'en français de France c'est le cas, mais pas au Québec.

Comment: @spaghettibaguetti Oui, c'est possible. J'ai tempéré et clarifié ma réponse en ce sens.

Comment: personne ne dit "abandon his classes" non plus. You "drop a class".

Comment: @PatrickT Qui a dit que ça se disait ?

Comment: je faisais référence à cette note en bas de votre réponse: "peut-être sous l'influence de l'anglais to abandon his classes ?"

Comment: @PatrickT Ah oui, une recherche m'avait montré des occurrences donc je ne l'avait pas exclu, mais elle semble très rare en effet.

Answer (score 0):

Les deux possibilités sont correctes autant du point de vue grammaire que du point de vue sémantique ; la première n'est pas aussi explicite que la seconde et c'est pour cela que pour une entrée en matière il est préférable d'utiliser la seconde mais ce n'est pas une véritable faute de ne pas le faire ; dans le cours de la discussion, comme le sujet est alors clair, on peut  utiliser la première, qui est énoncée plus rapidement.

*Autres façons de formuler cette idée (seulement quelques unes, il y  a un grand nombre d'alternatives)*

- Bien qu'il ait (déjà) la mention « bien » il abandonne ses classes !
- Il a (déjà) la mention « bien » et il abandonne ses classes !
- Avec pourtant la mention « bien » il abandonne ses classes !
- Il abandonne ses classes sans considération pour la mention « bien » qu'il a déjà !
- C'est surprenant mais la mention « bien » qu'il a dans ses classes ne l'empêche pas de les abandonner !
- Pour lui la mention « bien » qu'il a dans ses classes ne compte pas et il les abandonne !

Comment: Excellent. Merci beaucoup LPH.